# How to have partially pre-rendered fields using Django-haystack

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I've started using a rendered field in my django-haystack indexing to avoid database hits when a search is rendered.  This is working well for the most part, but I have some runtime information (such as an edit button for staff) in the results as well that I'd like to splice in. A simplified example:

```
{{object.name}}<br/>
{% if user.is_staff %}
    <a href="{% url object_edit pk=object.id %}">Edit</a>
{% endif %}
{{ object.description}}
```

The user logic obviously can't be applied at indexing time so doesn't occur. Without using javascript hacks is there a way to splice some runtime output in amongst the pre-rendered text?  I'm thinking it can be done by passing the rendered text with some formatting placeholders to a custom template tag, but I wonder if there's another way.

**Edit:** Perhaps multiple rendered, stored fields might be possible, covering the main fragments of the search result surrounding the logic parts, and then assembled at run time in the main results template. Would this work?

Comment: Any particular reason you can't just store the name and description instead? Storing an HTML fragment means you have to re-index if you want to change your template.

Comment: @Hamish, my real world example uses more fields across a few relations so storing the right ones in line with the template is likely to be cumbersome and error prone.  It's not a bad idea though as it still achieves the main aim of reducing DB hits

Comment: Could store the data as JSON... that would solve it, without having to store a template fragment.